# Will secure url be forced on canvas pages?

Tags: security, facebook

Will secure url be forced on canvas pages ?
Or will we able to continue serving our applications from normal urls ?
What exactly will happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to support ssl on my site that allows login through facebook connect](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7477394/do-i-need-to-support-ssl-on-my-site-that-allows-login-through-facebook-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developer roadmap, apps MUST obtain an SSL certificate. From https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/:

> 1. Apps on Facebook Authentication and security migration
>
> All Canvas and Page tab apps (that are not using FBML) must convert to process signed_request (fb_sig will be removed) and obtain an SSL certificate for use in ‘Secure Canvas URL’ and ‘Secure Page tab URL’ (unless you are in Sandbox mode).

I haven't seen any official statements regarding what will happen to apps that are not available via HTTPS by October 1st. I expect that many developers will not have that feature ready, so Facebook might just display a warning message for some time. But I guess that at some point, apps without a secure URL will not be made available any more. Of course, that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Official statement is that apps will enter a sandbox mode if secure_canvas_url isn't entered for an application.

Comment: as i searched it will be forced for only people who selects to use https. so i think applications will become broken for only https selected users.